# ngbTooltip along with ngb Pagination is not working

Tags: angular, pagination, tooltip

When I tried to use ngbTooltip for the cells in table and the table having nib-pagination.

tooltip is not working.

Any idea how to get the tooltip working along with ngb-pagination

Stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7t3y6f

in table-pagination.html file ngbTooltip is not working

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Shared the code - stackblitz link provided